# failed to add space between children of view container in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have a parent view container it contains another view having two button components.I need to have a space between the button components for that I add justify-content into the child view container,but it's not working.

**code**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { View,Image,StyleSheet,Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Card,Button,Avatar } from 'react-native-elements';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
export default class WelcomePage extends Component {
    render() {
        const {navigate}=this.props.navigation
        return (
            <View style={{flexDirection:'column',flex:1,alignItems:'center',justifyContent: 'flex-start'}}>
            <Avatar
              width={Dimensions.get('window').width}
              containerStyle={{flex:85}}
              avatarStyle={{flex:85}}
              imageProps={{resizeMode:'cover'}}
              source={require('../assets/images/logo.png')}
              onPress={() => console.log("Works!")}
              activeOpacity={0.7}
            />
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row',flex:15,marginTop:10,justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
                <Button  large title='LOGIN' icon={<Icon name="user-secret" size={25} color="white" />} buttonStyle={{height:50,width:130,backgroundColor:"#b3b3b3"}} titleStyle={{fontWeight:"700"}} containerViewStyle={{borderRadius:5}} borderRadius={5} />
                <Button  large title='REGISTER'  icon={<Icon name="user-plus" size={25} color="white" />} buttonStyle={{height:50,width:130,backgroundColor:"#b3b3b3"}} titleStyle={{fontWeight:"700"}} onPress={() => navigate('register')} containerViewStyle={{borderRadius:5}} borderRadius={5} />
            </View> 
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

**output**

[image]

using flexbox algorithm how can I add space in between the button components?

Comment: my flex wasn't 100% width by default, I had to give `width: '100%',` explicitly to the buttons row wrapper, and also give it `flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center',` and that worked just fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to remove the style `alignItems:'center'` from the parent wrapper.

Since `alignItems: 'center'` aligns your child elements to the `center`, then you can't see the effect of `justifyContent: 'space-between'`

Therefore modify your code as follows

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'column',flex:1,justifyContent: 'flex-start'}}> // Remove alignItems here
                <Avatar
                    width={Dimensions.get('window').width}
                    containerStyle={{flex:85}}
                    avatarStyle={{flex:85}}
                    imageProps={{resizeMode:'cover'}}
                    onPress={() => console.log("Works!")}
                    activeOpacity={0.7}
                />
                <View style={{flexDirection:'row',flex:15,marginTop:10,justifyContent:'space-between', paddingLeft: 20, paddingRight: 20}}> // Added some padding for a bettwer view
                    <Button  large title='LOGIN' icon={<Icon name="user-secret" size={25} color="white" />} buttonStyle={{height:50,width:130,backgroundColor:"#b3b3b3"}} titleStyle={{fontWeight:"700"}} containerViewStyle={{borderRadius:5}} borderRadius={5} />
                    <Button  large title='REGISTER'  icon={<Icon name="user-plus" size={25} color="white" />} buttonStyle={{height:50,width:130,backgroundColor:"#b3b3b3"}} titleStyle={{fontWeight:"700"}} onPress={() =>{}} containerViewStyle={{borderRadius:5}} borderRadius={5} />
                </View>
            </View>
```

Comment: thanks my friend,I also replace justify content of parent view as 'space between' and remove 'marginTop' from child view ,but it's not working???

Comment: Since the parent wrapper contains `flexDirection: 'column'`, therefore applying `justifyContent: space-between` to the parent wrapper would the children vertically along the `flex`, therefore what you're doing currently is correct, by applying `justifyContent: space-between` to buttons wrapper

Comment: is it possible to add space between button and the image using flexbox algorithm?

Comment: I need to check it what they are doing with `avatar containerStyle`, will get back to you soon.

Comment: Better way would be to assign `padding` in the buttons wrapper view, since if you use `justifyContent : space-between`, it would scale and look weird on large devices such as tablets, ipad.